# help with discrete math question for maximization and minimum suitability

Tags: discrete-mathematics, maxima-minima, discrete-optimization, matching-theory, transversality

Alice, Barbara, Curt, Danielle, Elmer and Fred work as car washers. Their suitability(as a score out of 10) for performing the tasks of hosing, scrubbing, window washing, vacuuming, polishing, waxing and are given in the following table

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\, & hosing &scrubbing &window-washing &vacuuming &polishing &waxing\\\hline
Alice    & 6 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 4\\
Barbara  & 7 & 9 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 3\\
Curt     & 0 & 0 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 2\\
Danielle & 0 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4\\
Elmer    & 7 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 6\\
Fred     & 4 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 6
\end{array}$$

1. Find a way of assigning the car-washers to the tasks so that the total suitability is maximized.
2. Find an assignment of car-washers to tasks in which the minimum suitability
   over all six car-washers is as large as possible.

Comment: Yes and I couldn't do it so I would appreciate the help

Comment: Good!  But *what* did you try?